# How can i get mySql column Length/Values

Tags: mysql

I can get column table information with this command, but that don't return column `Length/Values`, how can i get that?

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'tableName'
```

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand what you want here. The information_schema.columns column_type field describes the column attributes including the maximum length that can be held in that column. But if you want to know the actual maximum lengths then you have to look at the data in the table. Do you want all values from the table including the length of every column together with the description of the column from information_schema.columns?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes sir, problem resolved by this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/40175051/6599627

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SQL has a LEN() Function. Which will give you a length of a field. However updated would be the solution:

## UPDATED

```
SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Field'
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry you can't have spaces in the as "..." This should work:

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, LEN(COLUMN_NAME) as Column_Length, DATA_TYPE, LEN(DATA_TYPE) as Data_Length FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'tableName'

Comment: unfortunately i get this error: `#1305 - FUNCTION information_schema.LEN does not exist`

Comment: Sorry, LEN() Is an SQL function, mysql its LENGTH().

`SELECT COLUMN_NAME, LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) as Column_Length, DATA_TYPE, LENGTH(DATA_TYPE) as Data_Length FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'tableName' `

Comment: returned value is not correct, because `channelName` length is `varchar(30)`, by your command i get `11` on `Column_Length`

Comment: Ok so I searched around and found this
`SELECT CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Database'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'Table'
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Field'`
From here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927512/mysql-determine-longest-varchar-length

Answer (score 2):

Please check if **COLUMN_TYPE** is what you are looking for.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'tableName';
```

Also, you may refer all the columns in **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS**  table and query data that might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do is using the LEN() function as this example:

```
SELECT CustomerName,LEN(Address) as LengthOfAddress
FROM Customers;
```

So for your code should be:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, LEN(COLUMN_NAME) as NAME_LENGTH, 
DATA_TYPE, LEN(DATA_TYPE) as DATA_LENGTH 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'tableName';
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_len.asp) you have more information!