# Changed a varchar length from 80 to 160, but in the Base View it still shows up as 80?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I enforce the new varchar length throughout the database.
I simply edited the column I wanted and increased the varchar length from 80 to 160. However, while looking at the views, the Base View still has that column's length displayed as 80. It won't let me change it.

Comment: How did you change the length from 80 to 160?

Comment: I just edited the column. Changed it from 80 to 160.
Then found the view for it. The length is still 80.

Comment: What are these views?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175051/10498828 on how to get the column's size.